# Max-min involving positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization

Let $A_1, \dots, A_n \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be $n$ positive definite matrices, that is, $x^{\top} A_i x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{0 \}$. Let $\| A \|$ denote the spectral norm of a matrix $A$. Define $V$ as

$$ V:= \max_{\{A_1, \dots, A_n: \|S\| \leq 1\}} \min_{i} \{ \|n A_i - S\|\},$$
where $S = \sum_{i =1}^n A_i$. What is a non-trivial upper bound on $V$? Intuitively, I think it should be $1 - 1/n$ but I can't seem to prove it. I feel there should be standard technique to solve such questions but I haven't come across any.

Any leads or references will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the Weyl's inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $V:=\sup\limits_{\{A_1,\ldots,A_n>0:\,\sum_jA_j\le I\}}\min\limits_i\|nA_i-\sum_jA_j\|=n-1$.

On one hand, let $E_{ii}$ be the diagonal matrix whose only nonzero diagonal element is a $1$ at the $i$-th position. Then $\|nE_{ii}-\sum_jE_{jj}\|=\|nE_{ii}-I\|=n-1$ for each $i$. Since there exist sequences of tuples of positive definite matrices $\{(A_1^{(k)},A_2^{(k)},\ldots,A_1^{(n)})\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}A_i^{(k)}=E_{ii}$ and $\sum_j A_j^{(k)}\le I$, we have $V\ge n-1$.

On the other hand, when $n\ge2$, we have
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_jA_j\le I\le(n-1)I\le nA_i+(n-1)I,\\
&nA_i\le n\sum_jA_j\le \sum_jA_j+(n-1)I.
\end{aligned}
It follows that $-(n-1)I\le nA_i-\sum_jA_j\le(n-1)I$. In turn, $\|nA_i-\sum_jA_j\|\le n-1$ and hence $V\le n-1$. Therefore $V=n-1$ when $n\ge2$. Clearly this is also true for $n=1$.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!